# Check load time of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which downloads content from an external resource and then displays it.

How can I determine how long it takes to load this div ?

I could use javascript to output the current timestamp before the div and after and then use the difference in time to discover the load time :

pseudo code :

```
<script>
console.log(currentTime)
</script>

<div>
load external resource
</div>

<script>
console.log(currentTime)
</script>
```

Should I use a tool like dynatrace ?

This content is loaded synchronously. The content that is being loaded is javascript based.

Comment: Is the content loaded synchronously (in _JavaScript_) or asynchronously/not in _JavaScript_?

Comment: @PaulS. ive updated the question, does this suffice ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to do this in the *Console*, you can use [`console.time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.time) and [`console.timeEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.timeEnd)

```
console.time('loadDiv');

// load external resource synchronously

console.timeEnd('loadDiv'); // time taken logged
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a timestamp before creating the `DOMElement` and appending it, then create a timestamp after the actions were done.

### JavaScript

```
var starttime = new Date().getTime();

document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="chocolate">Hot Chocolate!</div>';
var endtime = new Date().getTime();

console.log('It took ' + parseInt(endtime-starttime,10) + 'ms');
/* document.body.innerHTML += '<p>It took ' + parseInt(endtime-startime,10) + 'ms</p>'; */
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vgYed/1/)

An online alternative to benchmark your JavaScript code is [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com)